# CDH 5.4.4 Sqoop 2 Job starting but never runs

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-cdh, hue, sqoop2

[Cloudera Community Post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/CDH-5-4-4-Scoop-2-Job-starting-but-never-runs/td-p/29701)

Using Hue in Cloudera 5.4.4, when trying to run a Sqoop 2 Job it says the `(i) The job is starting...` but it never actually runs the job. I see nothing in the Job Browser and nothing in the job's *SUBMISSIONS* list. I also do not see any errors in the logs.

This is on a stock Cloudera 5.4.4 (QuickStart VM) which I'm assuming has all of the components pre-configured correctly. Unfortunately this is all I have to go on is the lack of error messages & helpful reporting.

Comment: Do you have a little log icon after submitting the job? Do you see any error in the developer console or the /logs page of Hue?

Comment: When I tried to view these logs through Hue - it says the logs are not found. However, in /var/logs/sqoop2 there appears to be some logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on CDH5, the sqoop 2 server does make some logs available under `/var/log/sqoop2/sqoop.log`. In my case, the error was not providing a partition column. This is an optional parameter, but the error reporting in the Hue interface doesn't surface any of these details.

```
2015-07-27 07:52:09,728 ERROR server.SqoopProtocolServlet [org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPut(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:84)] Exception in PUT http://quickstart.cloudera:12000/sqoop/v1/job/1/start
org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0005:No column is found to partition data
        at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcFromInitializer.configurePartitionProperties(GenericJdbcFromInitializer.java:147)
        at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcFromInitializer.initialize(GenericJdbcFromInitializer.java:51)
        at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcFromInitializer.initialize(GenericJdbcFromInitializer.java:40)
        at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.initializeConnector(JobManager.java:449)
        at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.createJobRequest(JobManager.java:372)
        at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.start(JobManager.java:276)
        at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.startJob(JobRequestHandler.java:379)
        at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.handleEvent(JobRequestHandler.java:115)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.v1.JobServlet.handlePutRequest(JobServlet.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPut(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:79)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```